# IIS access log to SQL normalization

Tags: normalization, logs

I am looking for insert IIS 6.0 access log ( 5 servers, and over 400MB daily ) to SQL database. What scares me is the size. There is a lot of information you are duplicating (i.e. site name, url, referrer, browser) and could be normalized by index and look-up table.

Reason why I am looking for own database instead using other tools is that is 5 servers and I need very custom statistics and reports on each, few or all. Also installing any (specially open source) software is massacre ( need have 125% functionality and take months ).

I wounder what would be the most efficient way to do it? Is someone saw examples or articles about it ?

Answer (score 3):

I haven't done it myself, but there are several articles on using SSIS to transform the data. The principle will apply to other ETL tools I guess

- http://www.databasejournal.com/features/mssql/article.php/3650326/Using-SQL-for-IIS-Logs-Part-2.htm
- [MS Log Parser](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=890cd06b-abf8-4c25-91b2-f8d975cf8c07&displaylang=en)
- [How-To: SQL query IIS Logs with Log Parser](http://blog.trivadis.com/blogs/michaelkoenings/archive/2008/01/10/how-to-query-iis-logs-with-log-parser.aspx)

and

- [maybe for reporting only?](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyId=D81722CE-408C-4FB6-A429-2A7ECD62F674&displaylang=en)